# Generate all possible lists by replacing elements with 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations

I would like to create from a list all the different list were 0,1,2,3...all element are replaced by an other
For example, if the replacement item is 0:

```
L=[1,2,3]
->[1,2,3],[0,2,3],[1,0,3],[1,2,0],[0,0,3],[0,2,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]
```

So far, I've tried I managed to do what I whant using Itertools but only in the case where 1 value is replaced by 0
Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way using `itertools`. The benefit of this method is that it is lazy.

A new list is produced on every `__next__` call of the generator `transformer`.

Alternatively, as below, you can output all combinations by calling `list` on the generator function.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

A = [1, 2, 3]

def transformer(x):
    idx = chain.from_iterable(combinations(range(len(x)), i) for i in range(len(x)+1))
    for indices in idx:
        y = x.copy()
        for j in indices:
            y[j] = 0
        yield y

res = list(transformer(A))

print(res)

[[1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 3], [1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Everyone's trying too hard here.  We want each value to be either the original value or 0 -- we want pairs like (1,0), (2,0), and (3,0):

```
>>> from itertools import product, repeat
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> zip(L, repeat(0))
<zip object at 0x7f931ad1bf08>
>>> list(zip(L, repeat(0)))
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]
```

and then we can just pass that into [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> list(product(*zip(L, repeat(0))))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 0, 3), (1, 0, 0), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion. First, create a function that can generate a full combinations for each index of the input:

```
def full_combinations(d, current = []):
   if len(d) == len(current):
     yield current
   else:
     yield current
     for i in range(len(d)):
        if len(set(current+[i])) == len(current)+1:
           yield from full_combinations(d, current+[i])

combination_list = list(full_combinations([1, 2, 3]))
new_results = [[0 if c in i else a for c, a in enumerate([1, 2, 3])] for i in combination_list]
full = [a for i, a in enumerate(new_results) if a not in new_results[:i]]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 3], [1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not pretty, but I'm sure you can get this idea to work.

The idea is to use itertools.combinations to get all combinations of indices for every length, then we flatten this list with itertools.chain().

Then we loop through this list of lists, setting those indices to the replace character.

```
import itertools
l = [1,2,3]
replace = 0

indices = list(itertools.chain(*[list(itertools.combinations(list(range(len(l))),z+1)) for z in range(len(l))]))

allcombs = [[l]]
for i in indices:
    l2 = l[:]
    for j in i:
        l2[j] = replace
    allcombs.append(l2)

print(allcombs)
```

[[[1, 2, 3]], [0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 3], [1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

Comment: `[1, 2, 3]` is missing and it's horribly unreadable with 0 explanation.

Comment: Simply add:

    allcombs = [[l]]

At the initialisation of allcombs to include this case.

The idea is we get the combinations of all indices for different length combinations, then flatten the list with itertools.chain - and then loop through that list of lists setting those elements to the replace_char.